# Intellisense in Android Studio forever stuck on "Analyzing..."

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem where I cannot get any IntelliSense in my Android Studio, I tried reinstalling it a few times but nothing worked. I found similar problems were updating the Kotlin plugin to `1.5.0` solved the issue, but mine has that very version, to begin with. Any help?

btw I'm using java for my project

[image]

Comment: I have experienced the same. I have managed to resolve it after going to build.gradle and updating versions on depedencies and then doing a sync. This seems to work for me.

Comment: Reinstalling windows worked for me lol